# How do I write an rspec test if an array of hashes has a attribute/value pair

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given an array of hashes I want to check if each one contains a certain key and value. The following did NOT work:

```
      it { expect(some_array).to all( have_attributes(:some_key => 'some_value') ) }
```

I could not tell from the match error why it didn't work but I think it's something to do with expectations have_attributes has about the input arguments or environment.

Comment: Just a guess here, but what is subject.body? If subject is, say, a controller response object, then subject.body is a string, not a hash. Assuming that, you'd have to use `JSON.parse(subject.body)` instead

Comment: I've updated the question, it is an array

Comment: I'm mostly curious why have_attributes doesn't work in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a custom matcher as follows:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_member_with_value do |expected_key, expected_value|
  match do |actual|
    actual[expected_key] == expected_value
  end
end
```

Usage:

`it { expect(some_array).to all( have_member_with_value(:some_key, "some_value") ) }`

Sadly I'm not sure why the approach in the question does not work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a hash of multiple key pairs?  I want to match most of the JSON in a response but exclude the dynamic and always unique changing values for the server, for less brittle tests.

Answer (score 2):

I think the assertion does not work because `have_attributes` does not work with plain ruby hash *keys*. You can't access hash keys the same as attributes if you're using a vanilla Ruby hash.

Consider:

```rb
a = OpenStruct.new(hello: 'you')
b = { hello: 'you' }

a.hello # this is an attribute automatically defined via OpenStruct
=> "you"

b.hello # this is a regular ol' key
NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for {:hello=>"you"}:Hash
from (pry):79:in `<main>'
```

I believe the matcher would work if the object you were working with had the *attribute* accessor for whatever key-value you were looking for. Ex. If you had an array of OpenStructs, using both `match_array` and `have_attributes` would work. These are usually available automatically via metaprogramming if you're using a fancy library like ActiveRecord or OpenStruct.

Otherwise, you have to define these attributes yourself, or assert on the hash key rather than the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```
it do 
  expect(subject.body.map { |elem| elem[:some_key] }).to all( eq "some_value" ) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through `subject.body` and write the expectation within the loop
e.g

```
subject.body.each do |entry|
   it { expect(entry[:some_key]).to eq "some_value"}
end
```